# Usage of function casin in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to use the function casin from the complex.h library, but an error ocurres. This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <complex.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {

  double complex z = 1.0 - 1.0 * I;
  double complex arcz = casin(z);
  return 0;
}
```

I'm getting an "Undefined reference to casin"

Comment: Do you need to link in the math library with `-lm`? The directive `#include <math.h>` just imports the declarations of the math functions.

Comment: Please show your exact compuler version, compilation command, and all messages including warnings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You lacked `#include <complex.h>`, and need to specify the math library while compile, e.g.,

```
gcc -std=c11 -Wall test.c -o test -lm
```

Comment: The error persists. Note that using a real argument like casin(-2) everything goes well, but the signature of the function says  "double complex casin(double complex z)" so it should work properly with complex numbers. More info about the function http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/casin.html

Comment: your original error is `"Undefined reference to casin"` - do you mean it still persists?

Comment: Yes, same error. But this error doesn't appear using a real argument with the function.

Comment: what compiler are you using?

Comment: gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 4.8.4

Comment: I'm using `gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4)` - there is no such error with the command given in the answer

Comment: The above command line should not contain the `-c` option, as that will just compile "test.c" to a relocatable object file, not an executable. The `-o test` option will set the name of the object file to "test" instead of "test.o", which will add to the confusion.

Comment: The problem is not in the compilation flags. The function already works with real arguments, however the signature says that should also work with complex numbers. So, if you put a real number no error occurs but if you use a complex as an argument then you got the "Undefined reference to casin".

Comment: @IanAbbott that's correct, thanks (edited)

Comment: @CodeSniffer my bad, you should use `-lm` at the end (see edited)

Comment: @CodeSniffer refer to this as to why library should be placed at the end http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9417169/why-does-the-library-linker-flag-sometimes-have-to-go-at-the-end-using-gcc

Comment: The -lm flag does not matter at all, since the math.h library is not used in casin function. The library used is complex.h. So -lm flag does not change the error output.

Comment: @CodeSniffer I believe `<math.h>` is not the same as math library. The math library contains both `<math.h>` and `<complex.h>` - you need to specify the library even if `<math.h>` is not used in this case

Comment: note: a library can contain many headers

Comment: Solved. It works.