# Trouble Including Glib::Error in Shared Library Using g++

Tags: python, c++, swig, ld, glib

I'm trying to create a shared library (.so file I believe) for use with a Python script using SWIG. The program will compile and run fine on it's own, but when I create the shared library and try to import the library using, I get an error like so:

```
ImportError: /path/to/file.so: undefined symbol: _ZNK4Glib5Error4whatEv
```

I checked out the symbol using c++filt to see what was causing the issue:

```
c++file _ZNK4Glib5Error4whatEv ---> Glib::Error::what() const
```

I'm not really sure what's causing this error. I tried using pkg-config --cflags with glib-2.0 as the first library, but that didn't solve the issue. I read on some other posts about linking the LD path, but I'm not sure what that is or how to do it.

Additionally, I tried including an extra header in my CPP file

```
#include <glib/gerror.h>
```

But that didn't make a different either. Here are the steps I took before things didn't work:

1. Compile program and save *.o files using

   ```
    CPPFLAGS := i_include/ -rdynamic -Wall -ggdb3 -std=c++11 $(shell pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0 gtkmm-3.0
    ...
    g++ -c $(CPPFLAGS) $^ -o $@ -rdynamic
    //(This line executes for many files^)
   ```
2. Move to directory that contains the Python file that I'd like to call CPP funcitons from and create a .i file as an interface for SWIG/Python.
3. Run `swig -python file.i`
4. Run `g++ -shared /path/to/files.o -o newFile.so`
5. Import module in Python and try to run Python script, but get import error instead.

It seems like the only place I even have a call to Glib::Error is when I'm trying to open a file  that doesn't exist, but like I said, the program compiles and runs fine. If there's any information that I left out, comment and I'll add it!

**UPDATE**: I ran `ld -o outifle.o /path/to/files.o` and I hundreds of undefined reference errors (it look like every function call was undefined). Did I use `ld` wrong?

**UPDATE**: @AsteroidsWithWings was patient enough to suggest a solution that worked for other users, where linking the libraries comes at the end of a command. Unfortunately, this did not solve my problem. I placed the linking for every relevant Make directive at the end and repeated the below process.

**UPDATE**: @PhilipWithnall suggested that I run `pkg-config --cflags --libs ...` (addition of --libs flag). After recompiling and running again, this unfortunately did not solve my problem.

Comment: _"as the first library"_ What happens if you put it at the end?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the library linker flag sometimes have to go at the end using GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9417169/why-does-the-library-linker-flag-sometimes-have-to-go-at-the-end-using-gcc)

Comment: _"I hundreds of undefined reference errors (it look like every function call was undefined). Did I use ld wrong?"_ No; you'll be missing the definition/reference for every single non-inlined glib symbol used in your project.

Comment: We usually don't list library dependencies in `CPPFLAGS`. You should consult a Makefile best-practices guide.

Comment: I can try putting it at the end. It's not explicitly called right now though, since it's part of gtk+-3.0. I don't think that will answer my question either, since I'm compiling and then running `gcc -shared`, but I might be mistaken.

Comment: Where should I list the library dependencies instead? :-)

Comment: I've already suggested further research resources.

Comment: I can find a best  practices guide. However, I'm a little confused about the link you presented. I'm not sure how to apply it to my own situation. Like I mentioned, I'm compiling and *then* using `gcc -shared`

Comment: Regardless. You're putting the glib lib references first in your build commands. You said so yourself, and showed an example (it's done via your `CPPFLAGS`). But, with GCC, you list the libraries _after_ the modules that depend on them, otherwise nothing happens. So just do that - make them come after `$^`. It's up to you to find a way to structure your Makefile to achieve it in an elegant way, but for now, to solve this problem, you can just put your `$(shell pkg-config .....)` at the _end_ of the build command and observe that it now links properly, no?

Comment: You mean like so? My apologies, I'm new to Make and I didn't write this file, I'm only working with it.
`g++ -c $(CPPFLAGS) -o $@ -rdynamic $^`

Comment: Perhaps you should have a discussion with the person who wrote it. :)

Comment: No, I didn't say to move `$^`, but to move the Glib library flags. So that they come after `$^`. They can't come "after" a thing that's at the end! You could put `$^` before `$(CPPFLAGS)` I guess (for now).

Comment: I moved the $^ to immediately after the -c and before $(CPPFLAGS), and re-ran `gcc -shared /path/to/files.o -o outfile.so` but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Because you're not running the modified commands. You only re-ran a command that hasn't been changed. So it's not a surprise the result is the same. Do a rebuild with the new Makefile.

Comment: I `make clean; make`'d - I should've said that.

Comment: Then I don't know what the problem is. I suggest you discuss with the author of the Makefile. Good luck!

Comment: Try `pkg-config --cflags --libs` rather than just `pkg-config --cflags`

Comment: Added --libs and recompiled, but no dice.