# Connecting Python server to back-end C++

Tags: python, c++, linker, g++, swig

**Summary:**
I have a server using BottlePy that hosts a web-interface for the app I'm working on. The back-end was written in C++ because the original front-end was written using GTK+3. Since it was written using GTK+3, the front-end has a lot of signals to send to the back-end to trigger back-end functionality. I want to allow my Python server to send these same signals to the C++ back-end.

**Approach:**
I wasn't sure how to get started connecting a scripted language to C++, especially for dynamic requests and signalling, so I did some poking around and I learned about [SWIG](http://swig.org/). It's my understanding that SWIG creates a wrapper/interface as the "bridge" between Python and another language (C++ in my case). I followed the tutorial [here](http://swig.org/tutorial.html) for connecting a Python module, and then I tried to run my server, but it didn't work.

**Steps Taken:**
Changed compile line from:
`g++ -c $(CPPFLAGS) $^ -o $@ -rdynamic`

To:
`g++ -fPIC -c $^ -o $@ -rdynamic $(CPPFLAGS)`

`CPPFLAGS` uses `pkg-config` to generate the dependencies for the files being compiled. I can give more detail here if needed. I followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8140494/why-am-i-getting-a-gcc-undefined-reference-error-trying-to-create-shared-objec) which led me to move `CPPFLAGS` to the end of the line, since I was getting this error:
`ImportError: /path/to/file.so: undefined symbol: _ZNK4Glib5Error4whatEv`

I also added `-fPIC` which I believe I added after getting a shared library error that suggested it.

To set up the shared libraries, I created a `.i` file, as suggested in the tutorial linked above. Then I ran `swig -python file.i`, followed by `gcc -shared *object files* -o outfile.so`. Finally, I added an import statement to my server file and added a call to the appropriate function from the imported module. When I tried to run the server, I got the error mentioned above.

**Questions:**

- Is there another way to link my Python server to my C++ backend?
- Did I miss a step in my procedure?
- Why would I be getting a `reference not defined` error using this method when my program compiles and runs successfully using the original front-end?

**Additional Resources:**
I made a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62941906/trouble-including-gliberror-in-shared-library-using-g).
Post about the [linker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9417169/why-does-the-library-linker-flag-sometimes-have-to-go-at-the-end-using-gcc).

Thanks in advance!