# make command error: ld cannot find libraries that exist

Tags: c++, linux, makefile

I'm running make and ld will not find libraries that I have verified to exist using `dnf provides '*/libpthread.so'` for example. I get the following error code:

```
g++ -fopenmp -static -lpthread -o bayescan_2.1 start.o beta.o dirichlet.o RJupdates.o MHupdates.o likelihood.o read_write.o anyoption.o 
/bin/ld: cannot find -lpthread
/bin/ld: cannot find -lm
/bin/ld: cannot find -ldl
/bin/ld: cannot find -lpthread
/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:4: bayescan_2.1] Error 1
```

These libraries all are found in `/usr/lib64` on my chair's computing cluster. However the ld.so.conf file does not include a path that only goes to `/usr/lib64` and I don't have admin permissions to create a new .conf file in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/`.

Is there any way I can force make to search for the libraries in `/usr/lib64`?

Here is the actual Makefile in question:

```
# BayeScan makefile

bayescan_2.1: start.o beta.o dirichlet.o RJupdates.o MHupdates.o likelihood.o read_write.o anyoption.o 
    g++ -fopenmp -static -lpthread -o bayescan_2.1 start.o beta.o dirichlet.o RJupdates.o MHupdates.o likelihood.o read_write.o anyoption.o 

start.o: start.cpp errors.cpp anyoption.h global_defs.h
    g++ -fopenmp -c start.cpp errors.cpp 

beta.o: beta.cpp global_defs.h
    g++ -fopenmp -c beta.cpp 
      
dirichlet.o: dirichlet.cpp global_defs.h
    g++ -fopenmp -c dirichlet.cpp 

RJupdates.o: RJupdates.cpp global_defs.h
    g++ -fopenmp -c RJupdates.cpp 

MHupdates.o: MHupdates.cpp global_defs.h
    g++ -fopenmp -c MHupdates.cpp 

likelihood.o: likelihood.cpp global_defs.h
    g++ -fopenmp -c likelihood.cpp 

read_write.o: read_write.cpp errors.cpp global_defs.h
    g++ -fopenmp -c read_write.cpp errors.cpp 

anyoption.o: anyoption.cpp anyoption.h 
    g++ -fopenmp -c anyoption.cpp 

clean: 
    rm *.o bayescan_2.1
```

EDIT:

Turns out ld was trying to find static libraries with the -static flag. Removing this flag from the Makefile fixed the issue.

Comment: Use the -L option to specify library search path.

Comment: Libraries generally needs to be put *after* the object files that needs them on the command line.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the library linker flag sometimes have to go at the end using GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9417169/why-does-the-library-linker-flag-sometimes-have-to-go-at-the-end-using-gcc)

Comment: If that were the problem, there would be errors like "undefined reference to pthread_create", not "cannot find -lpthread".

Answer (score 2):

Simply add `-L/usr/lib64` to the link command. See [Directory Options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-12.1.0/gcc/Directory-Options.html#Directory-Options) in the GCC manual:

> `-Ldir`
>
> Add directory `dir` to the list of directories to be searched for `-l`.

If you can't or don't want to edit the `Makefile`, you can supply additional search directories through [an environment variable](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Environment-Variables.html)

> `LIBRARY_PATH`
>
> The value of `LIBRARY_PATH` is a colon-separated list of directories, much like `PATH`. When configured as a native compiler, GCC tries the directories thus specified when searching for special linker files, if it cannot find them using `GCC_EXEC_PREFIX`. Linking using GCC also uses these directories when searching for ordinary libraries for the `-l` option (but directories specified with `-L` come first).

For example, run this in your shell before invoking `make`:

```
$ export LIBRARY_PATH="$LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib64"
```

Comment: I guess I'm confused exactly how to do this. Do I edit the Makefile itself?

Comment: Yes, that should be fine, if it's not generated by something. But I'll edit with an alternative approach.

Comment: I should have given a better question. For example I already edited the first module as such: 

`g++ -fopenmp -static -lpthread -o bayescan_2.1 start.o beta.o dirichlet.o RJupdates.o MHupdates.o likelihood.o read_write.o anyoption.o -L/usr/lib64`

and

`g++ -L/usr/lib64 -fopenmp -static -lpthread -o bayescan_2.1 start.o beta.o dirichlet.o RJupdates.o MHupdates.o likelihood.o read_write.o anyoption.o`

and neither fixed the error.

Comment: Alright, I tried the export command as well and still get the error for some reason.

Comment: Maybe `/usr/lib64` is absent from the configuration with good reasons, such as being for a different platform than `g++` is building for? Try `--verbose` to see some more details about what's going on.

Comment: The library path does include /usr/lib64 from the verbose output. Same error though. 

Strange. I guess it must just be something with the cluster that I can't figure out.

Comment: @MilesAnderson If you run the command `file /usr/lib64/...` for one of the libraries that you attempt to build with, what does it say? Is the library matching your system?

Comment: @MilesAnderson Also, are you attempting to link with static libraries (library files ending with `.a`) or dynamic libraries (ending with `.so`)?

Comment: Ah ok. They show as being symbolic links to relative paths that don't exist.

`/usr/lib64/libpthread.so: symbolic link to ../../lib64/libpthread.so.0`

What should I do then? Also they are all dynamic libraries as far as I know.

Comment: Sounds like your servers are broken and misconfigured. No compilation flag will fix that.

Comment: Damn. Well you all did a great job. Thanks a million for the help. Definitely not the answer I wanted lol. I'll see if I can get in touch with the system admin.