# GCC cannot find existing library

Tags: c, postgresql, gcc, debian, ld

I am trying to write a small web application in C, which connects to PostgreSQL using `libpq`.
I installed `libpq` on Debian 13, and have used the following Makefile to build the source code:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -pthread -Ithirdparty -I$(shell pg_config --includedir) -L$(shell pg_config --libdir) -l:$(shell pg_config --libdir)/libpq.so
SRCDIR = server
THIRDPARTY_DIR = thirdparty
SOURCES = $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.c)
THIRDPARTY_SOURCES = $(wildcard $(THIRDPARTY_DIR)/*.c)
OBJS = $(SOURCES:.c=.o) $(THIRDPARTY_SOURCES:.c=.o)
TARGET = onio

$(TARGET): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJS)

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS) $(TARGET)

.PHONY: clean
```

Take a look at this line:

```
CFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -pthread -Ithirdparty -I$(shell pg_config --includedir) -L$(shell pg_config --libdir) -l:$(shell pg_config --libdir)/libpq.so
```

This Makefile later expands to something like this:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -pthread -Ithirdparty -I/usr/include/postgresql -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -l:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pq.so.5.15 -o onio server/database.o server/dotenv.o server/http.o server/main.o server/request.o thirdparty/cJSON.o thirdparty/cJSON_Utils.o
```

I get:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have gone to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`, and ran `ls *libpq*`. I've gotten:

```
libpq.a  libpq.so  libpq.so.5  libpq.so.5.15
```

Why is GCC not finding these existing libraries? I've tried `libpq.a` as well, and have tried `-lpq` before and none of that worked. When I tried `-lpq` (after the -I and -L), I would get:

```
database.c:(.text+0x75): undefined reference to `PQconnectdb'
/usr/bin/ld: database.c:(.text+0x8b): undefined reference to `PQstatus'
/usr/bin/ld: database.c:(.text+0x9e): undefined reference to `PQfinish'
```

Something's clearly wrong, and I can't find out what the error is. Does anybody know what is going on?

I've tried `-lpq`, `-l:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so`, `-l:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.a`, etc.

Comment: Remove the colon in `-l:$(shell pg_config --libdir)/libpq.so`. You should actually not need anything more than `-lpq` there, since `-l` is a shortcut saying to use the library search path (to which you added the directory with the `-L` option) and search for library files with standard library extensions. Or you can provide the full path, `$(shell pg_config --libdir)/libpq.so`, with no `-l`.

Comment: “undefined reference to \`PQconnectdb'” tells you the compiler found the library file (because the message about not finding it vanished when you used `-lpq`) but the symbol `PQconnectdb` is not defined in it (or in anything else in your link). Either something is wrong with the library or you used the wrong symbol name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [gcc manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gcc.1.html), you could find the following options:

```
 -l library
           Search the library named library when linking.  (The second
           alternative with the library as a separate argument is only
           for POSIX compliance and is not recommended.)

           The -l option is passed directly to the linker by GCC.  Refer
           to your linker documentation for exact details.  The general
           description below applies to the GNU linker.

           The linker searches a standard list of directories for the
           library.  The directories searched include several standard
           system directories plus any that you specify with -L.
```

In your example, you already stated the search path of the library with `-L` and using `-l` will find the stated library in the linker path you've already placed so you only need to do `-lpq`

Also, `libpq.so` is already in your default search path so in your case, you don't need to set any `-L`.

```
gcc -o myapp myapp.c -lpq
```

Note:
In Unix world, `-l<name>` will find either `lib<name>.a` or `lib<name>.so` in your search path. AFAIK, the default search paths are `/lib/` and `/usr/lib`. (Probably `/usr/local/lib` on some systems).

**Edit**
Seeing that you already tried `-lpq`, you can fix your problem by adding the object files in the `gcc` command before the linker stuff:

```
gcc -o myapp myapp.o file1.o file2.o file3.o -lpq
```

For more information:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9417294/9432116