# Error : undefined reference

Tags: linux, gcc, linker, makefile, installation

I am using linux-mint 11 and trying to install 'sendip' tool from project purple on my machine.

I don't know much about makefile and linux internals.

but when trying to install it,getting these errors.Please help me with the issue.

What is most important to me this time is to get this tool installed on my machine as soon as possible.

It is installed perfectly on red hat machine without giving any eroor.

I searched on internet and found many solutions but none of them is working out even some looks irrelevent to me but on the safe side I tried them all ...

```
1. LDFLAGS='-ldl' make install
2. sudo apt-get install glibc*
3. make CFLAGS="${CFLAGS} -ldl"
4. sudo apt-get install libjpeg62-dev
5.  sudo apt-get install libdb-devel
6. sudo apt-get install libdbl
```

Error :

```
  udit@udit-Notebook ~/Desktop/sendip-2.5-mec-0 $ make
   for subdir in mec ; do \
    cd $subdir ;\
    make  ;\
    cd ..  ;\
    done
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/udit/Desktop/sendip-2.5-mec-0/mec'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/udit/Desktop/sendip-2.5-mec-0/mec'
sh -c "if [ `uname` = Linux ] ; then \
gcc -o sendip -g  -rdynamic -ldl -lm -fPIC -fsigned-char -pipe -Wall -Wpointer-arith  
-Wwrite-strings -Wstrict-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Winline -Werror -g -Wcast-align  
-DSENDIP_LIBS=\"/usr/local/lib/sendip\" sendip.o gnugetopt.o gnugetopt1.o compact.o ; \
elif [ `uname` = SunOS ] ; then \
gcc -o sendip -g -lsocket -lnsl -lm -ldl -fPIC -fsigned-char -pipe -Wall  
-Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wstrict-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Winline -Werror 
-g -Wcast-align -DSENDIP_LIBS=\"/usr/local/lib/sendip\" sendip.o gnugetopt.o  
gnugetopt1.o compact.o ;\
else \
gcc -o sendip -g -rdynamic -lm -fPIC -fsigned-char -pipe -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite- 
strings -Wstrict-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Winline -Werror -g -Wcast-align   
-DSENDIP_LIBS=\"/usr/local/lib/sendip\" sendip.o gnugetopt.o gnugetopt1.o compact.o ; \
fi"
sendip.o: In function `unload_modules':
/home/udit/Desktop/sendip-2.5-mec-0/sendip.c:211: undefined reference to `dlclose'
sendip.o: In function `load_module':
/home/udit/Desktop/sendip-2.5-mec-0/sendip.c:240: undefined reference to `dlopen'
/home/udit/Desktop/sendip-2.5-mec-0/sendip.c:241: undefined reference to `dlerror'
/home/udit/Desktop/sendip-2.5-mec-0/sendip.c:243: undefined reference to `dlopen'
/home/udit/Desktop/sendip-2.5-mec-0/sendip.c:244: undefined reference to `dlerror'
/home/udit/Desktop/sendip-2.5-mec-0/sendip.c:246: undefined reference to `dlopen'
/home/udit/Desktop/sendip-2.5-mec-0/sendip.c:247: undefined reference to `dlerror'
/home/udit/Desktop/sendip-2.5-mec-0/sendip.c:249: undefined reference to `dlopen'
/home/udit/Desktop/sendip-2.5-mec-0/sendip.c:250: undefined reference to `dlerror'
/home/udit/Desktop/sendip-2.5-mec-0/sendip.c:265: undefined reference to `dlsym'
/home/udit/Desktop/sendip-2.5-mec-0/sendip.c:266: undefined reference to `dlerror'
/home/udit/Desktop/sendip-2.5-mec-0/sendip.c:268: undefined reference to `dlclose'
/home/udit/Desktop/sendip-2.5-mec-0/sendip.c:272: undefined reference to `dlsym'
/home/udit/Desktop/sendip-2.5-mec-0/sendip.c:273: undefined reference to `dlerror'
/home/udit/Desktop/sendip-2.5-mec-0/sendip.c:275: undefined reference to `dlclose'
/home/udit/Desktop/sendip-2.5-mec-0/sendip.c:279: undefined reference to `dlsym'
/home/udit/Desktop/sendip-2.5-mec-0/sendip.c:280: undefined reference to `dlsym'
/home/udit/Desktop/sendip-2.5-mec-0/sendip.c:281: undefined reference to `dlerror'
/home/udit/Desktop/sendip-2.5-mec-0/sendip.c:282: undefined reference to `dlclose'
/home/udit/Desktop/sendip-2.5-mec-0/sendip.c:286: undefined reference to `dlsym'
/home/udit/Desktop/sendip-2.5-mec-0/sendip.c:287: undefined reference to `dlerror'
/home/udit/Desktop/sendip-2.5-mec-0/sendip.c:288: undefined reference to `dlclose'
/home/udit/Desktop/sendip-2.5-mec-0/sendip.c:292: undefined reference to `dlsym'
/home/udit/Desktop/sendip-2.5-mec-0/sendip.c:293: undefined reference to `dlerror'
/home/udit/Desktop/sendip-2.5-mec-0/sendip.c:294: undefined reference to `dlclose'
/home/udit/Desktop/sendip-2.5-mec-0/sendip.c:298: undefined reference to `dlsym'
/home/udit/Desktop/sendip-2.5-mec-0/sendip.c:299: undefined reference to `dlerror'
/home/udit/Desktop/sendip-2.5-mec-0/sendip.c:300: undefined reference to `dlclose'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [sendip] Error 1
```

MakeFile Contents :

```
#configureable stuff
PREFIX ?= /usr/local
BINDIR ?= $(PREFIX)/bin
MANDIR ?= $(PREFIX)/share/man/man1
LIBDIR ?= $(PREFIX)/lib/sendip
#For most systems, this works
INSTALL ?= install
#For Solaris, you may need
#INSTALL=/usr/ucb/install

CFLAGS= -fPIC -fsigned-char -pipe -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings \
        -Wstrict-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Winline -Werror -g   
-Wcast-align \
        -DSENDIP_LIBS=\"$(LIBDIR)\"
#-Wcast-align causes problems on solaris, but not serious ones
LDFLAGS=    -g -rdynamic -lm
#LDFLAGS_SOLARIS= -g -lsocket -lnsl -lm
LDFLAGS_SOLARIS= -g -lsocket -lnsl -lm -ldl
LDFLAGS_LINUX= -g  -rdynamic -ldl -lm
LIBCFLAGS= -shared
CC= gcc

PROGS= sendip
BASEPROTOS= ipv4.so ipv6.so
IPPROTOS= icmp.so tcp.so udp.so
UDPPROTOS= rip.so ripng.so ntp.so
TCPPROTOS= bgp.so
PROTOS= $(BASEPROTOS) $(IPPROTOS) $(UDPPROTOS) $(TCPPROTOS)
LIBS= libsendipaux.a
LIBOBJS= csum.o compact.o protoname.o headers.o parseargs.o
SUBDIRS= mec

all:    $(LIBS) subdirs sendip $(PROTOS) sendip.1 sendip.spec

#there has to be a nice way to do this
sendip: sendip.o    gnugetopt.o gnugetopt1.o compact.o
sh -c "if [ `uname` = Linux ] ; then \
$(CC) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS_LINUX) $(CFLAGS) $+ ; \
elif [ `uname` = SunOS ] ; then \
$(CC) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS_SOLARIS) $(CFLAGS) $+ ;\
else \
$(CC) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $+ ; \
fi"

libsendipaux.a: $(LIBOBJS)
ar vr $@ $?

subdirs:
for subdir in $(SUBDIRS) ; do \
    cd $$subdir ;\
    make  ;\
    cd ..  ;\
    done

protoname.o:    mec/protoname.c
$(CC) -o $@ -c -I. $(CFLAGS) $+

headers.o:  mec/headers.c
$(CC) -o $@ -c -I. $(CFLAGS) $+

 parseargs.o:   mec/parseargs.c
$(CC) -o $@ -c -I. $(CFLAGS) $+

 sendip.1:  ./help2man $(PROGS) $(PROTOS) subdirs VERSION
        ./help2man -n "Send arbitrary IP packets" -N >sendip.1

 sendip.spec:   sendip.spec.in VERSION
        echo -n '%define ver ' >sendip.spec
        cat VERSION >>sendip.spec
        cat sendip.spec.in >>sendip.spec

 %.so: %.c $(LIBS)
        $(CC) -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $(LIBCFLAGS) $+ $(LIBS)

 .PHONY:    clean install

 clean:
        rm -f *.o *~ *.so $(PROTOS) $(PROGS) $(LIBS) core gmon.out
        for subdir in $(SUBDIRS) ; do \
            cd $$subdir ;\
            make clean ;\
            cd ..  ;\
            done

  veryclean:
        make clean
        rm -f sendip.spec sendip.1

  install:      all
        [ -d $(LIBDIR) ] || mkdir -p $(LIBDIR)
        [ -d $(BINDIR) ] || mkdir -p $(BINDIR)
        [ -d $(MANDIR) ] || mkdir -p $(MANDIR)
        $(INSTALL) -m 755 $(PROGS) $(BINDIR)
        $(INSTALL) -m 644 sendip.1 $(MANDIR)
        $(INSTALL) -m 755 $(PROTOS) $(LIBDIR)
        for subdir in $(SUBDIRS) ; do \
            cd $$subdir ;\
            make install ;\
            cd ..  ;\
            done
```

Comment: What happen if you change in makefile: `LDFLAGS=    -g -rdynamic -lm -ldl`

Comment: @Alessandro Pezzato no change,same error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Encountered the same issue in Linux Mint 13 and Ubuntu 12.04. Here's what I did to fix this issue:

Install gcc-4.4

> sudo apt-get install gcc-4.4

In the Makefile, set the 'cc' to point to gcc-4.4.

> CC= gcc-4.4

Comment: Thanks that really helped and I hope it can help many others like me too ... :-))

Comment: I faced the same issue with gcc 4.7.2 on Ubuntu 12.10. Is it a bug with gcc then?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're on Linux, it would appear that the LDFLAGS_LINUX variable is used instead of LDFLAGS. Try adding `-ldl` to that line.

Comment: @twalberg but it is already there in Makefile .I have added contents of makefile also above ,please have a look.

Comment: Ooops... my bad. The fact that it comes after `-lm` on the other lines, but before it on LDFLAGS_LINUX tricked my eyes...

Answer (score 0):

I've rather used solution proposed in:

[Why am I getting a gcc "undefined reference" error trying to create shared objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8140494/why-am-i-getting-a-gcc-undefined-reference-error-trying-to-create-shared-objec)

and

[Answer:Undefined reference to 'pow' even though -lm is a compile flag. [C]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35872122/721929)