# Undefined reference to 'pow' even though -lm is a compile flag. [C]

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, cc

Any reason

```
cc -g -lm -DBLITZ_HOST_IS_LITTLE_ENDIAN
```

would produce an error with code using `math.h`? Is it possible there's a difference between GCC version 4.0.3 (documented working version) and version 4.6.3 (my current version)?

`makefile` and `asm.c` @ https://gist.github.com/3801291

This is on ubuntu 12.04

My terminal output is a comment in the gist.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of

```
cc -g -lm -DBLITZ_HOST_IS_LITTLE_ENDIAN foo.c
```

Try:

```
cc -g -DBLITZ_HOST_IS_LITTLE_ENDIAN foo.c -lm
```

When the linker searches a library, it links in modules that contain definitions for previously-undefined symbols.

If the linker searches `-lm` before `foo.o`, then `pow()` is not yet undefined. Conversely, if `foo.o` comes first, it undefines `pow()`, which `-lm` can then resolve.

---

**EDIT**: To accomplish this advice in **your** makefile, make these changes:

```
CFLAGS=-g -DBLITZ_HOST_IS_LITTLE_ENDIAN
LDLIBS=-lm

...

asm: asm.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) asm.c $(LDLIBS) -o asm
```

Comment: Then tell us more about your compilation environment, the precise *entire* command line, and a sample program.

Comment: I just noticed the makefile still puts -lm before asm.c so I'm going to try and go around that now and see if it works.

Comment: Much appreciated. Thanks. I did come across another error though. SHould -m32 be added before or after the code file?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17308/discussion-between-bsull-and-rob)

Answer (score 0):

I've recently suffer this problem using an automatic builder, namely [drone.io](https://drone.io/).

The problem was that gcc in Ubuntu 12.04 was linking by default with *-Wl,--as-needed*.
In my case, the project was using autotools, which means I was too lazy to write anything to modify the compilation order. Instead, modifying *as-needed* flag fixed the problem.

```
-gabriel_LDFLAGS = $(GLIB2_LIBS) $(DBUS_LIBS) -lssh
+gabriel_LDFLAGS = -Wl,--no-as-needed $(GLIB2_LIBS) $(DBUS_LIBS) -lssh
```

For full info, you can check the fixing commit in https://bitbucket.org/kikeenrique/gabriel/commits/f08eefdca3f7bb90f48f5a6fbfc8839422572508

You can take a look [to the log with errors **BEFORE** applying the fix](https://drone.io/bitbucket.org/kikeenrique/gabriel/3) and also you can take a look [to the log without errors **AFTER** applying the fix](https://drone.io/bitbucket.org/kikeenrique/gabriel/4).