# Linker errors-Undefined Reference to

Tags: c++, linker, linker-errors, netbeans-7.1

I have project which has a dependency of a logging project when i build this other project i get the following linker errors:

The logging project build well however when i use the logging project inside this project as a library in linker options it generates the following errors , in my logging project i do have a logger.cpp in which wxRegKey is defined.

```
../logging/dist/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows/liblogging.a(Logger.o): In function `ZN7Logging6Logger17CreateRegistryKeyEv':
c:\logging/impl/Logger.cpp:125: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN8wxRegKeyC1ENS_6StdKeyERK8wxString'
c:\logging/impl/Logger.cpp:127: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN8wxRegKeyC1ENS_6StdKeyERK8wxString'
c:\logging/impl/Logger.cpp:129: undefined reference to `_imp___ZNK8wxRegKey6ExistsEv'
c:\logging/impl/Logger.cpp:135: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN8wxRegKeyD1Ev'
c:\logging/impl/Logger.cpp:140: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN8wxRegKeyC1ENS_6StdKeyERK8wxString'
c:\logging/impl/Logger.cpp:142: undefined reference to `_imp___ZNK8wxRegKey6ExistsEv'
c:\logging/impl/Logger.cpp:143: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN8wxRegKey6CreateEb'
c:\logging/impl/Logger.cpp:149: undefined reference to `_imp___ZNK8wxRegKey6ExistsEv'
c:\logging/impl/Logger.cpp:152: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN8wxRegKeyD1Ev'
c:\logging/impl/Logger.cpp:155: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN8wxRegKeyC1ENS_6StdKeyERK8wxString'
c:\logging/impl/Logger.cpp:156: undefined reference to `_imp___ZNK8wxRegKey6ExistsEv'
c:\logging/impl/Logger.cpp:157: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN8wxRegKey6CreateEb'
../logging/dist/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows/liblogging.a(Logger.o): In function 
`ZN7Logging6Logger13GetLoggStatusEv':
c:\logging/impl/Logger.cpp:169: undefined reference to     
`_imp___ZNK8wxRegKey8HasValueEPKc'
c:\logging/impl/Logger.cpp:170: undefined reference to 
`_imp___ZNK8wxRegKey10QueryValueEPKcPl'
c:\logging/impl/Logger.cpp:176: undefined reference to 
`_imp___ZN8wxRegKey8SetValueEPKcl'


../logging/dist/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows/liblogging.a(Logger.o): In function  
`ZN7Logging6Logger12SetLoggLevelEv':
c:\logging/impl/Logger.cpp:186: undefined reference to    
`_imp___ZNK8wxRegKey8HasValueEPKc'
 c:\logging/impl/Logger.cpp:193: undefined reference to 
`_imp___ZN8wxRegKey8SetValueEPKcRK8wxString'
c:\logging/impl/Logger.cpp:200: undefined reference to `_imp__wxConvUTF8'
../logging/dist/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows/liblogging.a(Logger.o): In function 
`ZN12wxStringBase4InitEv':
C:/wxWidgets-2.8.12/include/wx/string.h:270: undefined reference to   
`_imp__wxEmptyString'
../logging/dist/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows/liblogging.a(Logger.o): In function `wxStringBase':
C:/wxWidgets-2.8.12/include/wx/string.h:368: undefined reference to   
`_imp___ZN12wxStringBase4nposE'
C:/wxWidgets-2.8.12/include/wx/string.h:368: undefined reference to 
`_imp___ZN12wxStringBase8InitWithEPKcjj'
../logging/dist/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows/liblogging.a(Logger.o): In function 
 `ZNK8wxRegKey10QueryValueEPKcR8wxString':
C:/wxWidgets-2.8.12/include/wx/msw/registry.h:167: undefined reference to    
`_imp___ZNK8wxRegKey10QueryValueEPKcR8wxStringb'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [dist/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows/abcproject.dll] Error 1
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/c/abcproject'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/c/abcproject'


 BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 34s)
```

order of include file in logger.h

```
 #include <vector>
 #include <sstream>
 #include <string>
 #include <ctime>
 #include <windows.h>
 #include <winbase.h>
 #include <wx/wx.h>
 #include <wx/thread.h>
 #include <wx/log.h>
 #include <wx/app.h>
 #include <wx/msw/registry.h>
 #include <wx/utils.h>
 #include <map>
```

Please help

Comment: Can you please edit your question to to show _how_ the program is linked?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have evidently neglected to include the library that defines several functions of the `wxRegKey` class. That's what the linker says it can't find. Are you sure *logger.cpp* defines `wxRegKey` *and* all of its methods?

I suspect your source code doesn't actually *define* anything related to `wxRegKey` since that's actually a class from an external library. Rather than *defining* that class, you've *included* a header file where that class is declared. The *definition* resides in an external file, and you need to tell your build system which file that is.

You have a *linking* error, not a *compiling* error, so the order of the `#include` statements is irrelevant. The compiler has already finished compiling everything by the time you see the errors you're reporting here. The compiler has converted your text source code into binary object code, and now the linker is trying to gather all the binary files together to form the final executable program. The binary files refer to some functions that the compiler was told would be defined somewhere else, and now the linker is trying to find those definitions, but it cannot.

If you don't know where the functions are defined, or how to tell your build system where to find them, then you might have to post another question: What do I need to link with to use wxRegKey? How do I link with wxWidgets in a NetBeans project? I don't know the answers to those questions because I've never used those tools.

Comment: i have a looger.h which i use in logger.cpp not aware of the sequence however i have got #include <wx/msw/registry.h> in logger.h

Comment: @LindaHarrison Rob Kennedy doesn't say you haven't do a header file inclusion - that would have resulted in a **compiler** error and not in a **linker** error.

Comment: @Rob Kennedy it's also possible that the order of the source files is wrong - newer GCC (rather ld) versions seem to be pedantic about that.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8140494/why-am-i-getting-a-gcc-undefined-reference-error-trying-to-create-shared-objec/8140599#8140599 for command line order being important.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to use `wxwidgets`. Are you sure you are linking the correctly library while linking the final executable? Please review the command passed to the linker.

Comment: yes i am ,in the additional directories under linker options i have written c:wxwidgets-2.8.12/lib/gcc_dll/msw

Comment: I'm afraid that is not enough. With "additional directories" you only tell your linker where to look for libraries, but do not explicitly tell it to use those libraries. Look for an option similar to "additional libraries".

Comment: I don't know what development environment you are using, but it sounds like it.

Comment: which specific library should i add then?

Comment: `wxwidgets`, that seems to be the library you are missing.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you forget add library `wxBase` to linker command line, besause of even `wxString`-symbols aren`t resolved.

Comment: u mean along with `wx-config --libs` -wxBase

Comment: Yes, something like this. What IDE do you using?