# gcc in Windows cannot compile C program written for Unix/Linux

Tags: c, windows, shell, gcc, cygwin

I am a Unix/Linux newbie who is trying to run a shell script written by a person who left no documentation and has since demised. This script contains line:

```
./search $opt1 $arg1 < $poly 2>&1 | tee $output
```

Which is trying to get the file `$poly` and call program `./search` and divert the output to `$output`.

When I get to this line, I am given message: `./search: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`

`search` is a C program called from the script and is in the same folder as various other C programs to do with this project. Script and C programs were developed and originally executed on a Unix/Linux box which is no longer available, so I have been asked to try to resurrect this project but under Windows using `gcc` in NetBeans and `cygwin`.

The message : `./search: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error` is most likely to do with the fact there is no executable file for `search`. When I try to build the C programs I get the following output:

```
C:\cygwin64\bin\make.exe -f Makefile
gcc -ansi -g -c cbuild.c
gcc -ansi -g -c complex.c
gcc -ansi -g -c mylib.c
gcc -ansi -g -c poly.c
gcc -ansi -g -c real.c
gcc -ansi -g -c zero.c
gcc -lgmp -lm -lrt -o cbuild cbuild.o complex.o mylib.o poly.o real.o zero.o
real.o: In function `rabs':
/cygdrive/c/../progs/real.c:9: undefined reference to `__imp___gmpf_abs'
/cygdrive/c/../progs/real.c:9:(.text+0x1e): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `__imp___gmpf_abs'
real.o: In function `radd':
```

I assume that `R_X86_64_PC32` refers to the environment I am using. I am using a 64 bit version of `Netbeans` with `gcc 5.4.0` in a 64 bit version of `cygwin` on `Windows 10`.

Can anyone advise what I must to to resolve this so that I can build the C programs?

Comment: cygwin is no Linux/Unix emulator.

Comment: Does a simple "*hello, world*" (http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c/213/hello-world/795/hello-world#t=201608131834051452644) compile, link and run?

Comment: "*not offer a run option*" err what? Just run it by doing `./myprogramname` ... :-S

Comment: Any ways: order matters when specifying libraries, as pointed out by *Chris Dodd*'s answer.

Comment: So it's probably a dupe to for example this one: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8140494/694576

Comment: On Windows, there is no need to prepend a `programname` with `./`. Just run it with `programname`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
gcc -lgmp -lm -lrt -o cbuild cbuild.o complex.o mylib.o poly.o real.o zero.o
```

By default, the linker will link libraries and objects in the order specified on the command line, and, when linking a library, will only include symbols needed by things *before* it on the command line.  Since `-lgmp` is first, there are (as yet) no outstanding symbols (except `main`), so nothing is included from the library.  When later objects need the symbols from it, they won't see them.

Change the order to

```
gcc -o cbuild cbuild.o complex.o mylib.o poly.o real.o zero.o -lgmp -lm -lrt
```

and it should work.  Alternately, use the `-Wl,--as_needed` linker option to get the linker to remember earlier libraries and relink them if more symbols from them are referenced by later object files (requires a recent version of the GNU linker -- I have no idea if it works with cygwin).

---

This kind of misordering is usually a symptom of a broken Makefile.  The normal Makefile structure has a bunch of variables that are set to control the default rules that know how to compile source files and link object files.  The two variables relevant for linking are `LDFLAGS` and `LDLIBS`, and the difference is that `LDFLAGS` comes *before* all the object files on the command line and `LDLIBS` comes *after* all the object files.

So in order to make things work, you need to ensure that all of the `-l` options and other libraries are in `LDLIBS`:

```
LDLIBS = -lgmp -lrt -lm
```

and *NOT* in `LDFLAGS`

Comment: My makefile has `LIBS   = -lgmp -lm -lrt` but there is no `LDLIBS` or `LDFLAGS`.

Comment: @MrMorgan: so your Makefile is very non-standard -- you need to look at how `$(LIBS)` is used, and fix that to make sure they are after the object files on the command line.