# SWIG Python Extension for Qt C++: Import Error Undefined Symbol

Tags: python, c++, qt, wrapper, swig

I have some Qt C++ code I would like to make a python extension for. The module is being created with no error, however, when I try importing it in python I get an `ImportError`

I googled the problem and apparently it's an issue linking the proper libraries, however, I've already tried linking all the Qt5 libraries.

Here is the header file of the code I am trying to wrap, token.h:

```
#ifndef TOKEN_H
#define TOKEN_H

#include <QVector>
#include <QString>

class Token {
private:
    QString name;
    int ID;

    //The pixel locations of the bounds of the bounding box
    //of the token.
    int top, bottom, left, right;

public:
    //Pointers to the tokens (shapes and letters) that are
    //direct children of the current token (i.e. not nested
    //within yet another token).
    QVector<Token *> childTokens;

    Token();
    ~Token();
    void setName(const QString &);
    void setID(int);
    void setBounds(int, int, int, int);
    void addChild(Token *);
    void addChildVector(QVector<Token *>);

    int getTop();
    int getBottom();
    int getLeft();
    int getRight();
    int getID();

    QString getName();
};

#endif // TOKEN_H
```

token.cpp

```
#include "token.h"

Token::Token() {
    top = 0;
    bottom = 0;
    left = 0;
    right = 0;
}

Token::~Token() {
    for(int i = 0; i < childTokens.size(); ++i) {
        delete childTokens[i];
    }
}

void Token::setName(const QString & nameVal) {
    name = nameVal;
}

void Token::setID(int IDVal) {
    ID = IDVal;
}

void Token::setBounds(int topVal, int bottomVal, int leftVal, int rightVal) {
    top = topVal;
    bottom = bottomVal;
    left = leftVal;
    right = rightVal;
}

void Token::addChild(Token * childToken) {
    childTokens.append(childToken);
}

void Token::addChildVector(QVector<Token *> childTokenVec) {
    for(int i = 0; i < childTokenVec.size(); ++i) {
        addChild(childTokenVec[i]);
    }
}

int Token::getTop() {
    return top;
}

int Token::getBottom() {
    return bottom;
}

int Token::getLeft() {
    return left;
}

int Token::getRight() {
    return right;
}

int Token::getID() {
    return ID;
}

QString Token::getName() {
    return name;
}
```

Here is the interface file, token.i

```
%module token

%{
#define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
#include "token.h"
%}

%include "token.h"
```

Here are the commands I run to create the python module token

```
swig -python -c++ token.i

g++ -c -fpic token_wrap.cxx -I/usr/include/python3.6m -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/

g++ -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lQt5Core -lQt5Gui -lQt5Concurrent -lQt5Xml -lQt5XcbQpa -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Test -lQt5Sql -lQt5PrintSupport -lQt5OpenGL -lQt5Network -lQt5EglFSDeviceIntegration -lQt5EglFsKmsSupport -lQt5DBus  -shared token_wrap.o -o _token.so
```

So the commands seem to run with no issue, but here is the error message upon attempting to import

```
python3
Python 3.6.8 (default, Jan 14 2019, 11:02:34) 
[GCC 8.0.1 20180414 (experimental) [trunk revision 259383]] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import token
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/danny/Desktop/sketch2code/Qt Project Files/token.py", line 15, in <module>
    import _token
ImportError: /home/danny/Desktop/sketch2code/Qt Project Files/_token.so: undefined symbol: _ZN10QArrayData11shared_nullE
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 62, in apport_excepthook
    import re, traceback
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/traceback.py", line 5, in <module>
    import linecache
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/linecache.py", line 11, in <module>
    import tokenize
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tokenize.py", line 35, in <module>
    from token import *
  File "/home/danny/Desktop/sketch2code/Qt Project Files/token.py", line 15, in <module>
    import _token
ImportError: /home/danny/Desktop/sketch2code/Qt Project Files/_token.so: undefined symbol: _ZN10QArrayData11shared_nullE

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/danny/Desktop/sketch2code/Qt Project Files/token.py", line 15, in <module>
    import _token
ImportError: /home/danny/Desktop/sketch2code/Qt Project Files/_token.so: undefined symbol: _ZN10QArrayData11shared_nullE
>>> exit()
```

---

**EDIT: Possible Solution If SWIG is not a Must**

I wasn't able to get this working with SWIG, although I'm certain there is a way to get it to work. Anyway, I'm adding this in case someone with my same question stumbles on this post.

I ended up using a more powerful tool for creating python bindings for Qt, Shiboken. It is able to create bindings for Qt slots and signals.

Here is a very helpful tutorial:  [Using Shiboken2 to create Python bindings for a Qt library](https://blog.basyskom.com/2019/using-shiboken2-to-create-python-bindings-for-a-qt-library/)
And here is the full documentation: [Shiboken the Binding Generator](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/shiboken2/index.html)

Although one quirk that I faced was that I needed to change the name of the `Token` class. At least when using the python3 interpreter, the class name `Token` gave me issues that were resolved by simply changing the class name. Other than that Shiboken was lovely and a pleasure to use.

Comment: It seems to me that you are using a wrong version QtCore or a mismatch. The version that your program expects is different from the version, which is found by Python. Try to make a simple executable first and see if this works. If okay, proceed and ensure Python loads the right `.so`

Comment: Does using this to link instead: `g++  -shared token_wrap.o -o _token.so -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lQt5Core -lQt5Gui -lQt5Concurrent -lQt5Xml -lQt5XcbQpa -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Test -lQt5Sql -lQt5PrintSupport -lQt5OpenGL -lQt5Network -lQt5EglFSDeviceIntegration -lQt5EglFsKmsSupport -lQt5DBus` fix it? I'd guess you're seeing this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8140599/168175

Comment: @JensMunk So the code runs in Qt creator fine, and Qt5 is the only version of Qt I have installed if that's what you mean.

Comment: @Flexo No, unfortunately, it didn't fix it, still the same error message. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: I have seen the same error when a wrong version of Qt was loaded. If you can supply a full example, I can see if I can make it work

Comment: @JensMunk I've added the toke.cpp file just now, is there anything else you might need? The Qt version I am using is 5.12.4

Comment: No, I will make it work tomorrow - time is 11 pm here... Till later

Comment: Unfortunately, I never figured out how to fix this, but in case anyone stumbles on this page with the same question, I ended up using shiboken, which is a much more powerful tool (at least for Qt) able to wrap Qt slots and signals. I'll edit the question and add a few links.